# underline not working properly in customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to underline a label in customtkinter but it is not working properly. I am using the following code...

```
instruction_head = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="Instructions",font=("bahnschrift semilight", 18), underline=True)

instruction_head.place(relx=.2, rely=.25, anchor=ctk.CENTER)
```

This yields the following result in my window

[Tkinter window displaying text in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lmoy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lmoy.png)

I need the whole word to be underlined and I don't see why this would be happening.

I have tried including the word "underline" in my font name string but that simply broke my font. I also tried using setting the value of underline to 1 but that was fruitless as well.

Comment: The `underline=` option takes an integer, which specifies the index of the single character to be underlined - the purpose is to indicate which character you type to activate the function.  (It's more generally used with Buttons than Labels.). And Python's `True` is a subclass of integer, with a value of 1, so you got the second character underlined.

Comment: @jasonharper What would be the syntax for underlining the entire word? All the documentation i've seen says to either use booleans or an int.

Comment: Try `("bahnschrift semilight", 18, "underline")` as the font specification.

Comment: That did it, Thank you. Why do you not put it as an answer and only a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`underline` expects an integer that represents a single character that should be underlined. This is for denoting keyboard shortcuts, it is not for underlining an entire word or string.

If you want the entire label string to be underlined, you must use a font that has the `underline` attribute turned on.

Since you're using a tuple to define the font, you can easily turn on the `underline` attribute there. The third and subsequent parts of the tuple definition can be used to defined the styles applied to the font.

```
instruction_head = ctk.CTkLabel(
    app, text="Instructions", font=("bahnschrift semilight",  18, "underline")
)
```